# mySQl - How to use MAX() function with other query attributes

Tags: mysql, sql, select, max

Good afternoon:
Given a certain database, I'm trying the following SQL query:

```
select id, date, shop, max(sold_units) from storage where id='9911110810110319890031009710810111097';
```

The SQL above compiles well, but I came across the following situtation: the column max(sold_units) shows the maximum value (correct), however, the other attributes (id, date, shop) are referencing another row, which is incorrect (because that other arrow does not have the maximum value of sold_units). How can I modify the query above so that the attributes "id", "date", "shop" are in the same row as max(sold_units).

In other words, it should show the id, date, shop and max(sold_units) from the row which has the maximum amount sold units.

Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is malformed.  It should be generating a syntax error, because the `select` has `max()` so this is an aggregation query.  But there is no `group by`.  And the `select` also has unaggregated columns.

I suspect that you intend:

```
select id, date, shop, sold_units
from storage s
where id = '9911110810110310511110897109971031009710810111097'
order by sold_units desc
limit 1;
```